# Css canvas circle stroke sharpness

Tags: css, canvas

I have a circle seek bar on my audio player which draws canvas circle in a timer interval. The problem is that as canvas gets redrawn it looses it sharpness. The code, when the canvas is drawn once, the normal circle is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zs2gqxk/

The relevant code in the fiddle is below

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();
}
```

Here its redrawn 50 times to show the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/4bf9ka49/

In second example edges get ugly. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` to you code to clear the canvas, so it won't make multiple in the same spot.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Here's a image of the first JSFiddle you shared, and my [code's](https://jsfiddle.net/4bf9ka49/3/) image.
[image: JSFiddle]

[image: My Code]

Identical.